# Image extends off page in IE

Tags: image

In my Wordpress site, using the  Responsive theme the header image extends off the page to the right in Internet Explorer (please see www.thetorquingpoint.co.uk) but is OK in Safari & Chrome.

Any help as to how to solve this issue would be much appreciated.